# To Transfer a value from javascript to another page

Tags: javascript, .net

A seating arrangement is to done and i want to pass the final no of seats selected to the cs page using hidden field ,please tell whether this work or propose another solution.......

```html
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="layout._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
   <div class="holder">
      <ol type="A">
   <li>
       <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/>
           <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/>
           <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/>
           <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/>
           <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/>
           <asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/>
           <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/><asp:Image ID="Image8" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <asp:Image ID="Image9" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/>
           <asp:Image ID="Image10" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/>
           <asp:Image ID="Image11" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/>
           <asp:Image ID="Image12" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/>
           <asp:Image ID="Image13" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/>
           <asp:Image ID="Image14" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/>
           <asp:Image ID="Image15" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/><asp:Image ID="Image16" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/Black.png" 
           Width="35px" onClick="diffImage(this);"/>

           </li>
  </ol>

  <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Value= "" />
      <p id="p1"></p>
      <p id="p2"></p>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
           onclick="Button1_Click1" />
           
   </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var count = 0;
   var str;
   function diffImage(img) {

       if (img.src.match(/red/)) {
           img.src = "red.png";
           window.alert('Seat unavailable');
           return false;
       }


       if (img.src.match(/green/)) {
           img.src = "Black.png";
           count = count - 1;


       }
      else {
           img.src = "green.png";
           count = count + 1;

       }

      /* if (img.src.match(/Black/)) {
           img.src = "green.png";
           count = count + 1;

       }*/
     if (img.src.match(/red/)) {
           img.src = "red.png";
           window.alert('Seat unavailable');

       }
       document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "No of seats selected" + " " + count;
       document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "Total Cost" + " " + (count * 120);


   }
   str = count;
   window.sessionStorage=
   document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = str;
    </script>
```

As you can see i have used a hiddenfield to store the value and want to access it in the cs page via a button click

**CS page**

```
  protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String codebehindvalue = HiddenField1.Value.ToString();
        Label1.Text = codebehindvalue;

    }
```

I want to show the value in the label.     Will This work Please
 Help!!!!!!

Comment: Can you please provide your html?

Comment: why don't you try it?

Comment: I did Try it's not working.....@user1490835

Comment: i have given the html @andrescpacheco pls ignore any editing mistakes i am a novice in stackoverflow editing.

Comment: This has to be done from codebehing? Why not use only javascript?
document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML = Count

Comment: tried that but i need d value in code behind which is not being possible using label and inner html

Comment: It is important dat i get d value on buttonclick